# Outlook 2013 - Intermittently Cannot view Public Folders - Wreaking havoc on my C# Apps

Tags: outlook-2013, autodiscovery

When I try to open "Folders" in Outlook 2013 (Public Folders), I click the "expansion arrow" and intermittently the expansion arrow disappears and no folders appear. If I close and reopen Outlook, it will allow me to view the public folders. This is happening to all users (5 or so out of 55) who have Outlook 2013. This wouldn't bother me so much except I have several Visual Studio C#.NET (Framework: 4.5) apps that access the Outlook public calendars. I get an error that "Object cannot be found", so (also intermittently) I cannot create/delete these calendar appointments which are used by the entire company.

Anyone encountered/solved this issue? It seems as it might have to do with Autodiscovery... I've turned off the "Windows Themes" (in the system settings) and "hardware acceleration" (from within Outlook) and that allowed me to switch views from "Mail" to "Calendar" to "People" quickly (prior to this, it was very slow), but didn't help with this issue. There was a Microsoft KB that we were to remove that was supposed to solve this, but it wasn't in stalled on our machines... I am testing Outlook now and trying to recreate the issue and it is working perfectly...

Comment: If you can't find a more general solution, build retry logic into the apps that access the calendar, and have them notify an administrator if retries fail for "too long".

Comment: Good idea. We tried that and unfortunately, we are holding off migrating all users to Office 2013 as retrying to connect to the public calendars doesn't seem to help.